# *** glibc detected *** invalid pointer: 0x00000031bee21188

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I've looked through similar questions on stackoverflow, but I'm still not sure how to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
extern char *  pop();
extern void push(char *);
int i;
int j=0;
//Resize the array to 1.1 it's size
void reSize(char* tag){

char *temp = malloc(1.1*sizeof(tag));
 for (i=0;i<(sizeof(tag)/sizeof(tag[0]));i++){
    *(temp+i) = *(tag+i);
}
free(tag);
tag = temp;
}
int compare(char* tag, char* popVal){
i=0;    
while (i<sizeof(tag)/sizeof(tag[0])){
    if (*(tag+i) == *(popVal+i)){
        i++;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }   
}
return 1;
}
void dothis(){
int ch;
int n=0;
char *tag = malloc(10* sizeof(char));
char *popVal;   
while ((ch = getchar()) != '>'){
    tag[n] = ch;        
    n++;
    if (n > (sizeof(tag)/sizeof(tag[0]))-1 ){
        reSize(tag);
    }
}
if (*tag == '/'){
    popVal = malloc(sizeof(tag));       
    popVal = pop();
    j--;    
    if (!(compare(tag,popVal))){ // Compare will return 1 if the same
        printf("Invalid");
        exit(1);
    }

}else{
    push(tag);
    j++;
}
free(tag);
free(popVal);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  int ch;
  while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
if (!(isalpha(ch) || ch == '<'))
  continue;
dothis();

  }
if (j != 0){
    printf("Invalid\n");        
    exit(1);
}

  printf("Valid\n");        
  exit(0);
}
```

then the external methods:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
static int top = 0;
static char * stack[100];

int isEmpty()
{
  return !(top);  
}

char *  pop()
{
if (isEmpty()){
    fprintf(stderr, "Stack is empty");      
    exit(1);
}   
top--;
  return (char *) stack[top]; 
}

     void push(char * thing2push)
{
    if (top == 100){
    fprintf(stderr, "Too many things in the stack");        
    exit(1);
}else{  
    stack[top] = thing2push;    
    top++;  
}
}
```

In a previous question, the selected answer was "passing a pointer to memory you haven't allocated with malloc will definitely not do good things.", but I"m pretty sure I allocated everything

Comment: `char*` doesn't default to `NULL` so you should probably iterate over your `stack` and set them to `NULL` explicitly before you do anything with it.

Comment: When you have a pointer, like `char *tag`, doing `sizeof` on that pointer returns *the size of the pointer* and *not* what it points to.

Comment: You also have memory leaks, as you allocate memory and directly overwrite the pointer with another pointer, thereby loosing the first pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bug:

```
popVal = malloc(sizeof(tag));       
popVal = pop();
```

You malloc an area and then immediately lose that value, replacing it with something from pop().

This is most definitely a bug:

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != '>'){
    tag[n] = ch;        
    n++;
    if (n > (sizeof(tag)/sizeof(tag[0]))-1 ){
```

You assign to tag[n] before checking the range of n. When you do check the range of n after the fact you use `sizeof(tag)`. `tag` is a pointer. It's size is 4 (32 bit) or 8 (64 bit). Neither size has anything to do with how big `n` can be before `tag[n]` writes into invalid memory.

Another bug:

```
char *  pop()
{
if (isEmpty()){
    fprintf(stderr, "Stack is empty");      
    exit(1);
}   
top--;
  return (char *) stack[top]; 
}
```

If you're a beginning C programmer, **never** cast a pointer. Because I doubt that you have learned enough yet to know if this is a good or bad idea.

The type system exists for good reasons and if it complains about some types not matching, it is far more likely to be right than you are.

Comment: For the first bug, I want popVal to = pop(), but pop will return a pointer that is the same size as tag.\

For the second bug, aren't I circumventing that by initializing tag to be size 10? then everytime n gets close to the size of the tag array, I realloc it.
For the third bug, our prof gave us the code, but I"ll it in mind when I'm doing my own programming

Comment: @user3365695: In C local variables have memory allocated for them when they are declared. That means that the 4 or 8 bytes for a pointer are already provided and you had no reason to malloc.

Comment: @user3365695: I thought I explained why tag is not size 10. tag is a pointer. It points to a memory area that you allocated with malloc. But the sizeof a pointer is only the size of the pointer. Not the size of what it points to.